# Replacing a java method invocation from a field with a method call

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javassist

I am trying to build a mocking framework in java which fits to a specific requirement of a project.

The scenario is, I have a method

```
 public String returnRandom(){

    String randomString = this.randomGenerator.returnRandom()

    }
```

The randomGenerator is a dependency of this class and is injected to the object only in runtime. Means it would be null if the object is created without the dependency injection framework.

During an isolation test, I want the replace assignment to the statement

```
this.randomGenerator.returnRandom();
```

with a method which returns a stray random value, say "Helloworld".

**I was trying to use javassist.expr.FieldAccess for the same, using which  I can replace the field to a no operation and method call can be modified using javassist.expr.MethodCall.**

**I am not able to figure out how to replace the field with a dummy or a no operation. Is this possible using java assist or should I go for a more low level bytecode manipulation like asm?**

Note:
I could achieve replacing of a method call which doesn't originate on a field  using javassist.expr.MethodCall. For example if the above example is

```
public String returnRandom(){

    String randomString = returnRandom();

    }
```

I am able to replace as

```
public String returnRandom(){

    String randomString = MockedString.getSampleRandom();

    }
```

Comment: There are two issues that come up when mocking, 1) describing the behavior of the mock objects, 2) injecting the mock objects.  (1) is inherently not lean because you may have different behaviors that need to be tested against.  A good unit test setup comes up with good defaults for the mock objects and injects them.  Unit tests further down can access these mock objects to alter their behavior.  Are you looking to inject the mock objects and are already satisfied with your systems method of creating and describing the mock objects?

Comment: Exactly, our target system architecture and process is aligned in a way that, for most of the objects we know their defaults (An activity carried out in the design phase itself.). Then the challenge is to define the tests. We are trying to simplify the test definition, with a closed framework  rather than a very open junit style test cases and empirical mechanisms like all pairs . And while executing these test definitions we were trying  to manipulate the byte code ( or source code ) to inject these mock objects.

Comment: To manipulate the byte code, can this be done in runtime?  I was under the impression that it could not.  This would be of concern because if there are hundreds of tests, recompiling for each test might make for a long unit test cycle.

Comment: Bytecode can be manipulated in runtime and there are libraries available are generally called  byte code engineering libraries (like java assist, asm). Yes, there is an latency overhead especially when all the tests are run in a continuous integration environment. We have managed this by taking advantage of the high modularity of our system and running the tests in parallel. When tests are run individually, it is well within the human response time (750ms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem using javassist.expr.MethodCall. Below is the expression editor class used for checking the feasibility.

This replaces the targetMethod call (**methodcalltoReplace**) with the code used to get a mock object.

```
new ExprEditor() {
        @Override
        public void edit(MethodCall m) throws CannotCompileException {
            try {
                if (m.where().getName().equals(sourceMethod)) {
                    if (m.getMethod().getName().equals(methodcalltoReplace)) {
                        if(lineNumberOfMethodcalltoReplace == m.getLineNumber()){
                            // The content of the hardcoded string can be replaced with runtime data
                            m.replace("$_ = ($r)"+"new com.nuwaza.aqua.sample.SampleForMethodInvocationFieldAccess().helloworld();");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.edit(m);
        }
```

For a detail documentation see,
[Javaassist tutorial, introspection and customization](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#intro)

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is to create an interface for the random generator, say:

```
public interface RandomGenerator {
  public String returnRandom();
}
```

Then your original random generator can implement this interface, and the class that uses a random generator can depend on a class with a `RandomGenerator` interface.

Once you have this, it is fairly straight-forward to test. You create a mock generator that does what you want:

```
public class MockRndGenerator implements RandomGenerator {
  public String returnRandom() {
    return "Helloworld";
  }
}
```

and when you're testing, you inject this class instead of the original.

```
public class Demo {
  public Demo (RandomGenerator rndGenerator) {
    this.randomGenerator = rndGenerator;
  }
  public String returnRandom(){
    String randomString = this.randomGenerator.returnRandom()
  }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

Since I can't add code in comments, here is the Mockito solution:

> you can always use Mockito to avoid creating physical mocks, and then you can set up expectations and inspections on the way

```
class Test {
  public static rndTest() {
    RandomGenerator rnd = Mockito.mock(RandomGenerator.class);
    Mockito.when(rnd.returnRandom()).thenReturn("Helloworld");
    Demo = new Demo(rnd);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you meza for the reply. This is exactly the problem we are trying to manage using a new testing framework. We used this approach before and resulted in a large number of java classes for mock. We were concerned with maintainability of the tests and wanted to build a better framework giving developers lesser overhead on writing and maintaining unit tests

Comment: Yes, this is simple and testable. And - more important - this leads to a good programming style.

Comment: aurnvg: you can always use `Mockito` to avoid creating physical mocks, and then you can set up expectations and inspections on the way.

  class Test {
    public static rndTest() {
      RandomGenerator rnd = Mockito.mock(RandomGenerator.class);
      Mockito.when(rnd.returnRandom()).thenReturn("Helloworld");
      Demo = new Demo(rnd);
    }
  }

Comment: I've appended this solution to my answer

Comment: Thank you again. We tried mockito too. But the result was not fitting into the lean philosophy we are following. We wanted a more leaner test source files . We are looking into the byte code engineering and source code manipulation options to make the size of our test source files leaner. And we tried the existing testing frame works and they were not meeting our requirements.

Comment: Generally speaking if it's hard to test, there is most likely a design problem with the original class. :)
Also, if you feel like you're repeating yourself whilst writing tests, that might be another indicator that something else is wrong. Most mocking frameworks do the job well and if your design is good, they are not invading the test classes at all.

Comment: Thank you meza, We are a kind, doing an R&D and trying to find a mechanism of testing which is more leaner, maintainable and cost efficient. We have studied the existing mechanisms and evaluated the pros and cons. And trying to make POCs in search of better mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I have done in the past is to create a back door static method to replace your random generator with a mocked version.  You can then use mockito to instruct what it should return.  By making it static you avoid having to create many of them, just one for the whole class.  Like anything else it has pros and cons but it might fit your specific need.

Instead of called the field directly, like you are in your example, you could use a method instead getRandGen().  That method would either use the local random generator or the mocked static one if it is set.

Essentially this is a back door to overwrite your dependency framework's chosen object with one you select yourself at runtime during unit testing and it is static so it affects the whole class and not only specific instantiations.

Comment: Thankyou Jose Martinez. Basically you are suggesting to make the access of the dependencies from a separate method (mostly would be private). Our framework could achieve it meeting our (stringent) requirements. (Please see the example in the Note added in the question). But we were concerned about the "Usability" aspect. This means that developers have to code, keeping in mind, the constraint of the testing tool. This is the last thing we want to do ... that is to intrude into the developers freedom of writing code.

Comment: Hmmm.  That might be a subjective issue.  Tell your developers unit testing is a first class citizen, it gets on the train first. All problem child dependencies must have a back door entry for mocking it out. This solves the problem of creating a lot of classes because your mocking framework can detect the static setters and can insert mock objects for the developers.  The developers can then decide which of these mock objects they want to mock further.  You can even write your classes with suggested default mock objects so that they do not need to engineered during unit testing.

Comment: Thank you Jose Martinez. :). We are looking to solve problems, meeting our objective and not compromising on the constraints of the game. For us the developers are like our customers, demanding a better user experience.

Comment: Understood.  I'll keep my eyes open to see what else I can find that may help you out.